# how to fill missing values with a specific set on string values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, missing-data, fill

This is my DB,

[image]

its got too many missing cases for me to do it manually, and I can not use flash fill in this case,
so I want to randomlly fill these case with a specific set of strings :"TCS", "TCLSH","TCEO", and "TCT"
how can I do it in excell please help and thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please explain the logic about the strings to be put in empty places (or the logic in the ones that already have a string)

Comment: What criteria decides what string to use? You could add a formula to the next column `=IF(G1<>"",G1,<other string criteria>)`. Fill that down and then copy/paste values into column G.

Comment: there is no criteria behind it, it's a choice the student makes for their future studies,

Comment: If there's no criteria, than what is your question?

Comment: hmmm... in that case, filter to where you only see the rows with blank values and put this formula `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,4),"TCS", "TCLSH","TCEO", "TCT")` or a non-volatile version could be `=CHOOSE(MOD(ROW(),4)+1,"TCS", "TCLSH","TCEO", "TCT")`.  Just joking - with no criteria, there is no way to decide how to complete the missing data.

Comment: "randomly fill....".  commenters - isn't this clear enough?

Comment: yes it is clear thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a separate column using index with randbetween (per screenshot / [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j963RGgsveC9Gyi_7q?e=0Rv0Gv) sheet) as follows:

```
=IF(B3="",INDEX($H$3:$H$6,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($H$3:$H$6))),B3)
```

[image: Screenshot]